# how can I change numericInput type from list to numeric?

Tags: r, shiny

I took some inputs from the user by using numericInput function and these inputs should be put in an equation and give the final value, but I realized that the type of the inputs taken are  list and it gives me an error during the calculating equation.
So what should I do?

inputs

```
 distance_s_to_s <-(numericInput('distance.from.source.to.site','#Distance From Source To Site',value = 10 ,width = NULL)),
                                   distance_o_t <- (numericInput('distance.from..origin.to.Tehran','#Distance From Origin to Tehran',value = 10,width = NULL)),

                                   volume <-(numericInput('X.The.volume.of..moved.goods ','#The Volume of Moved Goods',value = 10 ,width = NULL)),
                                   percent_rev <- (numericInput('X.percentage.of.reversibility ','#Percentage of Reversibility',value = 10 ,width = NULL)),
                                   road_type <-(numericInput('X.Road.type','#Road type',value = 10 ,width = NULL)),
```

the output and equation is:

```
server<-function(input,output,session){
 
  
  

    coefs <- coef(test_model_2)
      
      calculatedvalue <- reactiveVal()
      
      calculatedvalue <- eventReactive(input$do,{
        
        
        coefs[1]+coefs[2]*distance_s_to_s+coefs[3]*distance_o_t+coefs[4]*volume+coefs[5]*percent_rev+coefs[6]*road_type
        
        
        
      })
      
      output$result <- renderText(calculatedvalue())
      
      
    }
     
      
    shinyApp(ui=ui,server = server)
```

and the error I get is

> Error in *: non-numeric argument to binary operator

`

Comment: Hi Melanii. From you post it looks like your trying to pass a list of 'numericInput' functions to the 'distance_s_to_s' function. You could try looping over the input list: for (val in input) {         
coefs[val]+coefs[val]*distance_s_to_s+coefs[val]*distance_o_t+coefs[val]*volume+coefs[val]*percent_rev+coefs[val]*road_type  
}

Answer (score 0):

the exact problem was the type of the numericInputs .they are lists and they can't multiply with coefs because they are integers. but I fixed the problem just by changing my inputIds.It seems that the past inputIds couldn't refer to the values of input lists.

```
(numericInput(inputId = 'Id1','#Distance From Source To Site',value = '' ,width = NULL)),
(numericInput(inputId = 'Id2','#Distance From Origin to Tehran',value = '',width = NULL)),
(numericInput(inputId = 'Id3','#The Volume of Moved Goods',value = '' ,width = NULL)),
(numericInput(inputId = 'Id4','#Percentage of Reversibility',value = '' ,width = NULL)),
(numericInput(inputId = 'Id5','#Road type',value = '' ,width = NULL)),                                                              
 coefs[1]+coefs[2]*input$Id1+coefs[3]*input$Id2+coefs[4]*input$Id3+coefs[5]*input$Id4+coefs[6]*input$Id5
```

Comment: Seems that the issue was the way you were referencing the inputs - in this answer example you use `input$xxx` format. Probably it would work if you did `input$distance.from.source.to.site`. In any case, if you answered your own question, be sure to accept it!